# Unity 3D and Gnome 3 aren't working

Tags: unity, drivers, gnome, graphics, 3d

When I first got my laptop, Unity 3D worked fine.  Then, suddenly, it stopped.  Then, regardless of which desktop environment I chose, it booted Unity 2D. I tried installing my ATI/AMD graphics drivers, and only the non-post-release on installs.  That doesn't even fix the issue.

Assuming it was an issue with Unity, I installed Gnome 3.  To my surprise, the same issue occurred again!  When I told it to boot Gnome, it went to Gnome Classic.   Please help me!  I would really like to have Ubuntu up and running on my laptop before I start college.

Comment: I don't know about why Unity 3D stopped working for you but Gnome-shell is not compatible with many ATI graphics card.

For instance, I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 550v and gnome-shell display is all pink/purple/white lined.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's similar to my problem.

I can't login in Unity 3D and GNOME 3 if my local network is turned on but cable isn't connected. Try to turn off the network in `network-manager` and then restart your laptop, login in Unity 3D. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring because the graphic cards 3D capability aren't enabled. You must enable them to get full 3D.

What are the results of:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

and

```
glxinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's similar for me. A few minutes ago I've updated some packages of Gnome Classic and after that when I exited from my session Unity 3D and Gnome Classic didn't work anymore. But Unity 2D and Gnome Shell ran fine.

First, I thought that ATI drivers crashed. So I uninstalled it but nothing changed.

Tomorrow I'll see if there are changes (via update manager) and if not, I'll do a Unity reset, hope this works.

---

**UPDATE:**
Solved, again in Unity 3D.
The commands

```
sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
```

didn't work for me. So the solution was a `unity --reset`.